# Why does "sys.sql_expression_dependencies" doesn't have any reference for stored procedures in Azure Data Warehouse?

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql, powerbi, azure-synapse

This is for Azure Data Warehouse.

I am trying to create a report in Power BI that displays tables used in stored procedures. I am able to do something similar for views but unable to do the same for stored procs. The "sys.sql_expression_dependencies" table has record for views reference but doesn't have any reference for stored procs. Below is the query I am using that gives zero records.

```
   SELECT   sproc.referencing_id as sproc_id
            ,o.name AS sproc_name
            ,referenced_entity_name AS table_name 
            ,type_desc
    FROM    sys.sql_expression_dependencies sproc
    LEFT JOIN sys.objects o WITH (NOLOCK) 
        ON sproc.referencing_id = o.object_id 
    WHERE type_desc like '%Procedure%'
```

My questions are

- Why the system table doesn't have any records for stored procedures but has reference records for views? Is there any trigger or something that's disabled?
- Any other way round to get list of tables used in stored procedures that I can display on Power BI?

I am trying to avoid doing a search for table names in sys.sql_modules.definition column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I researched on my end and found as per Microsoft documentation "sys.sql_expression_dependencies" should contain dependencies information for stored procedures.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-expression-dependencies-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

I posted the same question on MSDN forum to see if I am missing any settings in Azure Data Warehouse. The moderator checked with the product team and confirmed that at this time the "sys.sql_expression_dependencies" only contains dependencies for views. They are going to update the documentation soon.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/84493a3b-fc2c-4009-82f5-2e7cc56c3eed/why-does-8220syssqlexpressiondependencies8221-doesnamp39t-have-any-reference-for-stored?forum=AzureSQLDataWarehouse

Hope this is helpful for anyone who is looking for stored procedure and tables linking.